# salt stack source bashrc each time bashrc is updated

Tags: salt-stack

The bashrc files for my minions is a managed file, now I need to source the bashrc file each time it is changed is there a way to do that in salt.

Currently I have this

```
/home/path/bashrc:
  file.managed:
    - name:  /home/path/.bashrc
    - source:  salt://dir/bashrc
    - user:  path
    - group:  path
  cmd.run:
    - name:  source /home/path/.bashrc
    - user:  path
```

is this the correct way to do this ?

Comment: Can you please give the intention for calling source? If it is for setting environment variables in the current shell this setting will only be effective for the shell started by cmd.run and lost once the command returns. AFAIK it will have no effect on the minion or the shell that started the minion.

Comment: the states running after the  state mentioned above needs the env variables getting changed in the .bashrc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't and don't need to do that - `source` only works for the currently open terminal session. Salt can't (or shouldn't) abort/interrupt existing terminal sessions just to source a new bashrc.

A new version of bashrc will be sourced automatically when the user logs in next time.